# Sort highly-voted self-answers at the top

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, sorting, self-answer, score

I know that accepted self-answers are not sorted at the top of the page to prevent cheating, but I think that if the answer is voted highly enough, it should be displayed at the top. For example, [this highly voted, accepted self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1107556/1721527) was perfect for what I needed, but I almost didn't see it because, even though it had a score of >100, it was at the bottom of the page, buried below two answers that were each <10.

Can't we make an exception for highly-scored, accepted self-answers like these, and allow them to sort at the top?

Comment: [meta-tag:status-norepro] What sort order are you using?

Comment: You are sorting the question by 'oldest' sorting; sort by votes instead.

Comment: @Mysticial I didn't report it as a bug :) I was sorting by active. I switched to votes, and now it sorts better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, self-answers are sorted according to the current sorting order instead.

Normally the accepted answer is pinned at the top, and although self-answers are not given that privilege, they are still sorted *normally*. They are not delegated to the bottom either!

When you sort that post by votes, the self-answer is right there at the top. In fact, only when you sort by 'active' is it listed at the bottom. Fix your sort choice instead.

Comment: Just switched my sort order. Never noticed that it was sorting by active. Is that the default?

Comment: @jdwire: Votes has always been the default. The only way it would change to one of the other two is if you changed it (it remembers what option you select, even if you go to different questions). You probably changed it and forgot (I've done that before).

Comment: No, `votes` is the default, but the order is sticky.